# tax-exclusive or tax-inclusive?

Tags: meaning

I may need someone knowing about accounting to answer this for me:

On the contract,the show fee I should pay to a artist is$10,000.
20%($2,000) goes as withholding tax and 80% ($8,000)goes as the exact transfer amount received .

under this circumstance,the note I put behind the show fee($10,000) should be "tax-inclusive" or "tax-exclusive"?

Thanks again!

Comment: What country?  In the US I do not think we say "tax-exclusive" at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tax rates can be presented differently due to differing definitions of tax base, which can make comparisons between tax systems confusing.

In a tax-exclusive base, the tax rate is $2000/$8000 = 25%, whilst in tax-inclusive base, the rate is  $2000/$10000 = 20%.

Therefore, the $10000 are tax-inclusive (or inclusive of all taxes).

*The $8000 are tax-exclusive, but according to the official base of 20%, such wording should be avoided in the order or invoice*.

Comment: @Sandy - In case of withholding tax, you should mention "Witholding tax" and tax rate (20%) in order to avoid any misunderstanding on the amount of the final payment of $8000.

Answer (score 0):

I will use Google's dictionary here.

```
gross
     2. (of income, profit, or interest) without deduction of 
        tax or other contributions; total.
```

Thus the $10,000 fee before tax is the *gross fee*.

Now Merriam-Webster:

```
net  
     1. free from all charges or deductions: as
       a. remaining after the deduction of all charges, outlay, 
          or loss <net earnings> <net worth> — compare gross
```

Thus after the deduction of taxes we are left with $8,000, the *net fee*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unsure, then the other party/ies may also be unsure. Why not just spell out exactly what you mean? There's no benefit to being pseudo-legalistic when plain English can do the job. The fee is $10000, 20% of which will be withheld for taxes, leaving a net payment of $8000.